# Porque sale Null resultado de Api

Tags: php, null

Esta es mi Api:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
{
  if(isset($_GET['email_user']) && isset($_GET['password_user']))
  {
     $email_user=$_GET["email_user"];
         $password_user=$_GET["password_user"];
     $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();

    $query = 'SELECT id_user,email_user,password_user from users where email_user = ? AND password_user = ?';
    $result=$connection->executeQuery($query,array($email_user,$password_user));

    if ($result>0)
    {
            $user = json_encode(array(
                             'id_user' => $result[0][0],
                             'email_user' => $result[0][1],
                             'password_user' => $result[0][2]
                         ));
         echo json_encode(array(
             'status' => 0,
             'user' => json_decode($user)
             ));
    }//if
    else
    {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 1,
        'errorMessage' => 'user not found'
        ));
    }//else
  }
}
```

Al probar la api en postman asignando parametros para recibir la unica informacion perteneciente a ellos me sale este error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\sasy\apis\login.php** on line **20** 
>   
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\sasy\apis\login.php** on line **21** 
>   
>  **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\sasy\apis\login.php** on line **22** 
>   {"status":0,"user":{"id_user":null,"email_user":null,"password_user":null}}

Son esta lineas:

```
'id_user' => $result[0][0],
'email_user' => $result[0][1],
'password_user' => $result[0][2]
```

Si hago la consulta en mi manejador de base de datos, me tra la informacion segun el email y password asignado

Asi es como pongo los parametros en postman

```
http://localhost:8080/sasy/apis/login.php?email_user=juanperez@gmail.com& password_user= 123
```

El email y contraseña si existen en la base de datos.

Comment: No tienes que usar dos índices, sino uno: `$user = json_encode(array(
                             'id_user' => $result[0],
                             'email_user' => $result[1],
                             'password_user' => $result[2]
                         ));` porque no es un array que está dentro de otro array lo que te devuelve el método. Si no funciona, haz un `var_dump($result);` y pon el resultado en la pregunta para revisarlo.

Comment: De esa manera me sale lo siguiente  `Undefined offset: 0,1 y 2` y el var_dumb me regresa un array(0)